# How to solve a integer part inequality?

Tags: inequality

> $[x+2]>3$

I was thinking to just do $x + 2 >3$ and then it will give me $x > 1$ so I add the difference between $3$ and $2$ only to the right part, because not adding it will give me $x \in (1,+\infty)$ so if I plug in $1.99$ it will give me $3$ which is not good because $3 > 3$ is false.

Comment: Your question is barely intelligible. Are you trying to solve $\lfloor x+2\rfloor>3$ ?

Comment: Yes,in my textbook is saying the integer part

Comment: Please rework your text.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lfloor x+2\rfloor=\lfloor x\rfloor+2$$ is always true and your equation reads

$$\lfloor x\rfloor>1$$ or

$$\lfloor x\rfloor\ge2$$ (as the LHS is an integer).

This occurs for all

$$x\ge2.$$

Comment: Ok,I am just learning these so I am sorry if I ask some silly questions.If it was >4 then it will be $x\ge3$?

Comment: @ROBOTICS: questions with "it" are meaningless. Is it understood ?

Comment: Yes..i understand